# How to make a UIScrollView, some UIButtons and UIPanGestureRecognizer work together?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer

I got a scroll view with a bunch of buttons, which I want to both touch and drag.

To choose if it's a touch or a drag (not drag of the scroll view, "physically" dragging the button), I check the pan gesture recognizer of the button to see how far away the drag would be, if it's over a threshold I snap the button into drag mode and, removing it from the scroll view and adding it to my view controller's view (at the same location, so looks like it's in the same place).

This all works kinda smooth, except when I want to scroll and the pan fires at the same time. I need a way for the pan gesture recognizer to choose, based on velocity, if the scroll view should scroll or the button should be dragged.

**The question:** Is there a way for a UIPanGestureRecognizer to tell a UIScrollView to continue scrolling and cancel itself?

Comment: What have you tried? You might try watching https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/235/ for some insights.

Comment: Add the code you tried..